# Forge didn't start after restart

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean, forge, laravel-forge

Am working with laravel forge,
today am just restarted forge from admin panel like in image

[laravel forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP61v.png)

but after restart, the server stopped and can't open it now

server giving me disconnected status when restart it

[server status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roTwG.png)

and when connecting with putty as SSH client he gives me "Connection timeout" message
Note : putty was working fine with server, but after server restart i can't connect.

anyone can help me and thank you.

Comment: you should post the error messages are you getting

Comment: @BenGooding am just added more details to question

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to connect to the server via ip address and your user and password via putty or other ssh client?

If that is not possible try to reach out to your VPS provider and through their Cpanel you can try to reboot the VPS or even retrieve the root password.

Comment: thank you for answer ^^, sure i'm trying to connect to server but putty still giving me "Connection timeout" message

Comment: Then I would definitely check it out through provider admin panel. Maybe they got an issue going on their side and it's a coincidence

Comment: Maybe, am just sent a ticket to service provider, I hope find answer from any one or help from them, thank you Rudolf.